# Find all subgroups of the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

> For $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $k < n,$ let $R_k = \begin{bmatrix}\cos (\theta_k) & -\sin(\theta_k)\\
> \sin(\theta_k) & \cos(\theta_k)\end{bmatrix}$ and $F_k = \begin{bmatrix}\cos (\theta_k) & \sin(\theta_k)\\
> \sin(\theta_k) & -\cos(\theta_k)\end{bmatrix},$ where $\theta_k = \frac{2\pi k}n.$ Find all subgroups of the dihedral group $D_n = \{R_0,\cdots, R_{n-1}, F_0,\cdots, F_{n-1}\}.$

I know that by Lagrange's Theorem, the order of a subgroup must divide the order of a group. Since $|D_n| = 2n,$ any subgroup must have an order that's a divisor of $2n.$ But I don't think this helps much. I also know the following properties: for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_n$,

$$\begin{align}
R_a R_b& = R_{a+b},\\
 F_aF_b &= R_{a-b}, \\
R_a F_b &= F_{b+a},\\
 F_a R_b &= F_{a-b}.
\end{align}$$

Every subgroup contains the identity element of the group and for any elements $a,b$ in a subgroup $S, ab^{-1} \in S.$ I also know the subgroups of a cyclic group $G = \langle a\rangle , |G| = n$ are the subgroups $\langle a^d\rangle, d \mid  n,$ but I'm not sure if this is useful.

Comment: The rotations form a cyclic subgroup, which has subgroups of its own. Show that one rotation and one reflection generate the entire dihedral group. Then investigate what happens with two distinct reflections.